# ASP.NET LoginStatus inside LoginView doesn't trigger LoggingOut event

Tags: asp.net, loginview, loginstatus

I have a LoginView in my APS.NET application with AnonymousTemplate and LoggedInTemplate. I've  put LoginStatus control inside LoggedInTemplate but it doesn't work as expected.

Here's the code

```
<asp:LoginView ID="LoginView1" runat="server">
    <AnonymousTemplate>
        <asp:Login ID="Login1" runat="server" OnAuthenticate="Login1_Authenticate"
            DisplayRememberMe="False" PasswordRecoveryUrl="/" 
            DestinationPageUrl="/">
        </asp:Login>
    </AnonymousTemplate>
    <LoggedInTemplate>
        You are logged in as 
        <asp:LoginName ID="LoginName1" runat="Server"></asp:LoginName>.
        <asp:LoginStatus ID="LoginStatus1" runat="server" LogoutAction="Redirect" 
            LogoutPageUrl="/" onloggingout="LoginStatus1_LoggingOut" />
    </LoggedInTemplate>
</asp:LoginView>
```

All event handlers are correctly defined in code behind file.

The problem is that if user logs in he will see his user name with logout link from LoginStatus control. Clicking the logout link takes the user back to login form (both login and logout form are part of the same user control) but if I refresh the page the user is still logged in.

I've noticed that if I move LoginStatus control outside the LoginView then logout process works as expected. I've also noticed that when LoginStatus is inside LoginView then it doesn't raise a loggingout event.

Does anyone have any ideas what might be the problem?

Comment: I actually have exactly the same problem.  I have a LoginStatus control in the LoggedInTemplate and it does not fire the LoggingOut event.  I am not sure if it's valid to nest them like that.  It seems that on the postback (when clicking the Logout link) the LoginStatus control is no longer part of the page, therefore it doesn't fire the event.

Comment: Weird ... I've try the exact same setup as you on an application in .NET 4.0 I've maded and I don't have this problem ... Are you using Ajax or something like that on the page? Try to do this on a new project to see if it always do that. Are you using Visual Studio Devlopement Server or you are using IIS? Dunno if it can change something but it's only because I want to try to make my project looks like yours as much as possible.

Comment: It turned out to be Sitecore issue (although I haven't mentioned that I'm using that on Sitecore) and in normal ASP.NET project this isn't an issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm running into the same issues here. The loginstatus control outside of the loginview control works as desired. It seems silly that it won't work within the loginview control.

EDIT**
OK, so I left out that I was building this page in Sitecore. Apparently Sitecore somehow meddels with the loginview control and must be added to the following section in the web.config:

```
  <sitecore>
    <rendering>
      <typesThatShouldNotBeExpanded>
        <type>System.Web.UI.WebControls.LoginView</type>
      </typesThatShouldNotBeExpanded>
    </rendering>
  </sitecore>
```

[Thank some other guy...](http://www.bolaky.net/post/LoginView-control-not-working-when-logging-out-from-Sitecore-extranet-domain.aspx)

-Victor F.

Answer (score 1):

```
FormsAuthentication.SignOut()
FormsAuthentication.RedirectToLoginPage()
```

Also have you used form authentication in proper way i mean did you put a web config in inner directories?

```
<system.web>
<authorization>
  <allow users="?"/>
</authorization>
```

Answer (score 1):

I am experiencing the same problem. But my solution was to swap out the loginstatus control for a hyperlink control and have the hyperlink navigate to my home page with a querystring parameter attached like "logout=true" and then on my home page check Request.QueryString for the value and if it is not null the do this.

```
FormsAuthentication.SignOut();
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried changing your `LogoutAction` to `LogoutAction="RedirectToLoginPage"`?  I usually let .NET handle clearing the cookie which makes the `OnLoggingOut` event not needed.